# iphone-bitly question

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am using https://github.com/st3fan/iphone-bitly classes and as the example i want to do something for which i want your help.

```
- (void) demo
{
   URLShortener* shortener = [[URLShortener new] autorelease];
   if (shortener != nil) {
      shortener.delegate = self;
      shortener.login = @"LOGIN-REPLACE-ME";
      shortener.key = @"KEY-REPLACE-ME";
      shortener.url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://stefan.arentz.ca"];
      [shortener execute];
///// I want to get result on here not in the delegate for further usage in my function
   }
}
```

any help or suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're requesting would block the current thread. If you ran that on the main thread, you'd hang your app. The framework you've linked only provides an asynchronous interface for that reason.

If you're already running this on a background thread, you can re-implement `execute` to use `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]`. But never run that on your main thread.

Comment: i want to get result in my  demo funtion is there anyother class or something like that by using that i can get short link in my function  demo?? or in other words i can't move to anywhere unless i can't have short link. any idea ?

Comment: Yes, by rewriting URLShortener -execute to use sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error: and running `demo` on a background thread. I would recommend, however, that you just wait for the delegate callback and continue in a `demoFinish` method. This is the normal way to handle network fetches. You don't block the main thread waiting for them.